# Angular Event Emitter Output returning undefined

Tags: angular

I have 3 components, 1 Parent and 2 Siblings. I want to pass the data from Child 1 to the Parent and then to Child 2.

Child 1 - Gets data from a JSON file and renders it in a list. Then when a list item is clicked, it fires a function that passes its data.

HTML

```
    <li *ngFor="let data of data$ | async" (click)="projectSelect(data)">
      <div class="listIcon {{data.id}}"></div>
      <p>{{data.title}}</p>
    </li>
```

TS

```
import { FetchDataService } from './../fetch-data.service';
import { Component, Renderer2, ElementRef, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'project-navigation',
  templateUrl: './project-navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-navigation.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectNavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef, private FetchDataService: FetchDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() { this.fetchProjects() }

  data$;

  @Output() projectSelectEvent = new EventEmitter<Event>();


  fetchProjects() {
    this.data$ = this.FetchDataService.fetchProjects();
  }
  projectSelect(data: Event): void {
    this.projectSelectEvent.emit(data);
  }
}
```

App.Component - Catches Data

HTML

```
    <div class="content">
        <project-navigation (projectSelectEvent)="childProjectSelect($data)"></project-navigation>
        <project-overview></project-overview>
    </div>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'journal';

  public clickedProject: Event;

  constructor() { }


  childProjectSelect(data: Event) {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

This returns me an " undefined ", if I console.log the Child 1, I get the data I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to change the `$data` reference in your HTML template to be `$event` instead as that is the syntax for grabbing the event object that is emitted: `(projectSelectEvent)="childProjectSelect($event)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment you need to do only one minor change in app.component.html

```
(projectSelectEvent)="childProjectSelect($event)" change $data =>$event
```

working link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-854kh1